# Error in LLVM 13 documentation for little-endian vectors?

Tags: llvm-ir

LLVM 13 [added a short note](https://reviews.llvm.org/D94964) on the bit representation of sub-byte elements to its [documentation on vector types](https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/docs/LangRef.html#vector-type). I can follow everything it says except for the memory diagram for little endian which doesn't look right and disagrees with my experiments. I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding something:

> The same example for little endian:
>
> ```
> %val = bitcast <4 x i4> <i4 1, i4 2, i4 3, i4 5> to i16
>
> ; Bitcasting from a vector to an integral type can be seen as
> ; concatenating the values:
> ;   %val now has the hexadecimal value 0x5321.
>
> store i16 %val, i16* %ptr
>
> ; In memory the content will be (8-bit addressing):
> ;
> ;    [%ptr + 0]: 01010011  (0x53)
> ;    [%ptr + 1]: 00100001  (0x21)
> ```

I agree that `%val` has value `0x5321`, but shouldn't the memory layout be `0x21 0x53` (`33 83` in decimal) instead of `0x53 0x21`? For example, bitcasting `%val` to `<2 x i8>` yields `<i8 33, i8 83>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, It was an error. Fixed in this commit: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/9a53fe50f4355e6dfcd6af534cb394a62128963b